# mouse movement across multiple monitors

Tags: ubuntu, multiple-monitors, ubuntu-10.04, mouse

I have a dual monitor setup with my left monitor pivoted counter clockwise so it is portrait layout.  When my mouse rolls to the right off the left monitor onto the right monitor the cursor jumps down 25% of the screen or so.  Can someone point me to some documentation or
some software that can correct this so I can have my mouse cursor seamlessly go from one monitor to the next.

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and since I have a monitor pivoted I added an option RandRRotation to my xorg.conf which is preventing the System-->Admin-->Monitor app from coming up saying the RANDR extension isn't available.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Steve

Answer (score 1):

The resulution of the monitors should be the same also you can change that transition from one monitor to other in contorol panel.

Comment: The resolutions are the same but my left monitor is pivoted so instead of 1600 by 1200 widescreen it is 1200 by 1600 portrait.  So when I roll my mouse off the top right corner of the left monitor it shows up correctly in the right monitors top left corner but it's physically lower than my left monitor.